# How to create Debian preseeded ISO from macOS?

Tags: macos, debian, preseed

I would like to create a preseeded Debian ISO, but I only have a Mac available to do this.

The [instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Preseed/EditIso) for creating the ISO is straightforward, but it involves the appending of a file using `cpio`, which is not supported on the Mac.

Has anyone successfully created a Debian preseeded ISO from a Mac and can share alternative instructions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

There's a web based build service for custom Debian installation ISO images. It does not use the Debian installer, but instead the FAI system.

Have a look at https://fai-project.org/FAIme

Answer (score 0):

Honestly mate when I've had to do this , I've spun up virtualbox and worked on the ISO in there.